# Adding hyperlink with href to named formatting I18n vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js, href, vue-i18n

I've looked at the vue documentation on this page to see how I can solve this: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#named-formatting

I think i have all the syntaxes correct and I have tried many different scenarios with the href code.

This is the english translated file from my json file:

```
"link": {
  "text": "Click this {Url} link."
}
```

This is from my template:

```
 {{ $t("Message.link.text", { Url: <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">www.google.com</a> }) }}
```

This does not work and it displays `{{ $t("Message.link.text", { Url: www.google.com }) }}` in the UI.

Appreciate all the help I can get, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot output HTML with interpolation (`{{ }}` syntax) in Vue. You can use `v-html` for that but it is dangerous (see [the warnings in the docs](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#html-formatting))

Use [Component interpolation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage) instead:

```json
"link": {
  "text": "Click this {url}.",
  "link": "link",
}
```

Template:

```html
  <i18n path="Message.link.text" tag="p">
    <template v-slot:url>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">{{ $t('Message.link.link') }}</a>
    </template>
  </i18n>
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing an updated answer to Michal's answer, based on apparent API differences in recent version of vue-i18n ([see docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component#component-interpolation)). This is mainly for anyone coming here using Vue-3 and the current vue-i18n implementation (9.8.0).

This worked for me, while the "link" as an object did not:

```
"link.text": "Click this {url}.",
"link.link": "link"
```

And then (note i18n-t and keypath):

```js
<i18n-t
  keypath="link.text"
  tag="p"
>
  <template #url>
    <a
      :href="https://www.google.com/"
      target="_blank"
    >
      {{ $t('link.link') }}
    </a>
  </template>
</i18n-t>
```